# Did the pope try to suppress the number zero?

Tags: middle-ages, mathematics, pope

Is there any evidence indicating that the Pope attempted to suppress the number zero?

[In an editorial review](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0140296476), Rob Lightner claims that "Zero: The Biography of a Dangerous Idea", by Charles Seife, explains "Why did the Church reject the use of zero?". On the other hand, "God's Philosophers: How the Medieval World Laid the Foundations of Modern Science",  by James Hannam, rebuts "the idea that the pope tried to suppress the number zero".

Comment: If the pope did, should I ask another question to know the why?

Comment: The first sentence is very wrong. It reflects the attitudes of perhaps 150 or 200 years ago. Nowadays the Middle Ages get their due. Look up Late Antiquity for one example.

Comment: @Felix, well, I deleted the first sentence to avoid any distraction in reference to the question's focus, but we should carefully take information distorting reality to replace fact with biased revisionism.

Comment: The BBC's [In Our Time](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p004y254) programme had an interesting episode on the history of Zero a while ago. The issue of any pope suppressing zero did not come up. To me esp. absent any motivation on behalf of the church the idea sounds like from the plot of the next [Dan Brown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_brown) novel (full disclosure: I'm not a fan :)

Comment: @Drux, I edited the question posting further information with some references :) :)

Comment: This should be posted on skeptics.

Comment: Thx, these additional references are welcome and somewhat helpful. BTW, you may also be interested in the German (ahem) historian Heribert Illig, according to whom the medieval period of European history did not exist, and there was a cover up that whole centuries were "inserted" after the fact ... :)

Comment: @Drux: Herr Illig is not alone, there are other people who peddle such theories. But I really think the less mention of them in this forum, the better...

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I see you point but when in doubt prefer to err on the side of humor :)

Comment: @Drux: Good point! :)

Comment: I would note the zero was an ARAB (Muslim) "invention," so the Popes  had at least some incentive to suppress it.

Comment: @TomAu you mean Arab inventions like the Arab digits (0, 1, 2, ...) that we all use. (Admittedly not in each and every case, as e.g. a pope Benedict XVI. might argue :)

Comment: @TomAu It was originally an Indian (Hindu) conception. It made its way to Europe via the Arabs, along with much lost Hellenic Greek mathematics.

Comment: @TomAu That's incorrect, the was a concept of zero both in Ancient Egypt and in early Indian civilizations, long before the Arabs. The Romans and Greeks knew about it, and the Middle Ages Christian debates about whether zero represents the void and the "absence of God" originate in (Hellenistic) Greek philosophers. The Arab _digits_ were indeed an Arab invention, however if the Popes had incentive to suppress one of the digits, then why not suppress all of them? 1,2,3 et al are no less Arab than 0 in that respect.

Comment: I stand corrected. Today, I would say that zero is an Arab "introduction" (to Europe), not invention. The rest of my earlier comment stands.

Comment: Zero is a dangerous number. It has a "Z" in it, that just shows how dangerous it is. Ever heard of a division by zero error? Deadly.

Comment: Sadly, we don't have any idea where Seife got references that the Church attacked the concept of zero. I'm Catholic, and I see no conflict between faith and reason. I would like to know the truth.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Sylvester_II#Abacus_and_Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numerals), **Pope Sylvester II** (Gerbert d'Aurillac, c943-1003), is credited with re-introducing the abacus into Europe without an explicit use of the number zero. This was because it had not been introduced in the European mathematical vocabulary (Fibonacci did this around 1202, and it took centuries for it to become established), rather than an explicit decree that it should be banned.

[image: Gerbert's abacus with representative numbers. Credit: nonagon.org]

A detailed description of how Gerbert's abacus worked can be found [here](http://nonagon.org/ExLibris/gerberts-abacus-illustrated).

It's also interesting to note that [Gottfried Leibniz](http://www.kerryr.net/pioneers/leibniz.htm) had a somewhat mystical interpretation of the binary numbers, with one representing God and zero the void.

Comment: Welcome to the site James! The wikipedia article you cite is actually sourced from "Zero: The Biography of a Dangerous Idea", by Charles Seife.  This link (http://yaleglobal.yale.edu/about/zero.jsp) confirms your point that Fibonacci introduced zero to Europe around 1202.  Good work!

Comment: @James,  how is it possible for even the Pope to remove zero from an abacus?   What did he do, have Franciscan monks nail the bottom row, right most top bead to the center board?   Make it a sin to slide the one bead?   Is that where the term naughty bit came from?

Comment: @JMS I've edited the answer to add a picture and link to how it worked.

Comment: @James,  thank you for the interesting post.  very nice.